# Weak* convergence equivalent to boundness, Banach-Steinhaus theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers.
How to prove that weak* convergence to $0$ of $(a_ne_n)\in l_\infty(\mathbb{R})$ is equivalent to $(a_n)$ being bounded?

I'm asking for help, how to relate this to Banach-Steinhaus theorem of uniform boundness?

Comment: What is $(e_n)$. You may need to state the problem in full, defining all symbols.

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan I suspect that $l_\infty(\mathbb{R})$ is the space of bounded sequences on $\mathbb{N}$ and $e_n$ is the canonical vector that is $1$ on position $n$ and zero elsewhere, at least I wrote my answer under that assumption.

Comment: you may treat $a_n$ as a linear operator in the double dual space and apply uniform boundedness principle

Answer (score 1):

With regard to QuantumSpace's solution, we prove the $\Leftarrow$ direction:

Let $(a_{n})$ be a sequence of real numbers. For each $n$, define $\theta_{n}\in l^{\infty}$
by $\theta_{n}=(0,0,\ldots,0,a_{n},0,0,\ldots).$ Then, $\{\theta_{n}\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$
is a family of bounded linear functionals on $l^{1}$. We go to show
that $\sup_{n}||\theta_{n}||_{\infty}<\infty$ by Uniform Boundedness
Principle. Let $g\in l^{1}.$ Denote $g=(g_{1},g_{2},\ldots)$. By
assumption, it is given that $\lim_{n}a_{n}g_{n}=0$. Note that $\langle\theta_{n},g\rangle=a_{n}g_{n}$.
It follows that $\{\langle\theta_{n},g\rangle\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$
is bounded for each $g\in l^{1}.$ By Uniform Boundedness Principle,
$\sup_{n}||\theta_{n}||_{\infty}<\infty$. However, $||\theta_{n}||_{\infty}=|a_{n}|$.
Therefore, $\sup_{n}|a_{n}|<\infty$.

Comment: Remark: In the $\Leftarrow$ direction, the given condition can be
weaken as: For each $g\in l^{1}$, $\{a_{n}g(n)\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$
is bounded.

Comment: Nice solution +1

Answer (score 0):

Recall the canonical identification $(\ell^1)^* = \ell^\infty$ given by
$$\Psi: \ell^\infty \to (\ell^1)^*: f \mapsto \left(g \mapsto \sum_n f(n)g(n)\right)$$

Thus, by definition:

$a_ne_n$ converges weak$^*$-to $0$
$\iff$
$\Psi(a_n e_n)(g) \to 0$ for all $g \in \ell^1$.

Note that $$\Psi(a_n e_n)(g) = \sum_k (a_n e_n)(k) g(k) = a_ng(n) $$
so the latter condition is equivalent to $a_n g(n) \to 0$ for every $g \in \ell^1$.

Now, the claim follows from the following lemma which I leave as an exercise for you (see the other answer for a solution):

$$(a_n)_n \mathrm{\ bounded}\iff \forall g \in \ell^1: \lim_n a_n g(n) = 0$$

Comment: The $\Rightarrow$ direction is trivial but the $\Leftarrow$ direction requires some work.

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan Yes, basically it is a good exercise in real analysis.

Comment: If you try, you will find that directly proving the direction $\Leftarrow$ is not easy.

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan Guess you are right. It was harder than I thought.